# Repository query to search in a comma separated field

Tags: repository, typo3, extbase

I have a MySQL table for which I have a Repository and a Model. One column contains comma separated numbers and I need to check if one or more of my arguments match the comma separated numbers. Here's what the table looks like

```
| uid | groups | ...
|   1 |      2 | ...
|   2 |    1,2 | ...
|   3 |  3,1,2 | ...
```

In my repository I have the following

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->matching($query->in('groups', array(2, 3)));
```

This will match only record with uid = 1. Does TYPO3 have a solution for this kind of search without having to write a SQL query from scratch?

Comment: You might want to check the `FrontendUserRepository` from the extbase core, it has to deal with exactly this thing. I don't know how it's done, so I can't provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to manage it through model relations

Suppose you have USER model relation with GROUP model(M:N), and you have one relation property "group" in USER model relation Group model then you query in User repository will look like this:

```
$query->matching(
            $query->in('group.uid', $groupArray)
        );
```

This will return all user whose group in within $groupArray